# How to return JSON as a REST API without changing the routing of the page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, angularjs

The server sends back an 404 error after using a POST request with angular. I would like the ActionResult to return the JSON without redirecting or reloading the page.

ASP.NET MVC (Server):

```
public ActionResult Patient(LoginModel.UserInfo Model){
 //code is here 
 return Json(Info, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: hi, are you using AJAX post request?

Answer (score 0):

Decorate your action with the `HttpPost` attribute.  Your action could possibly be only hit for GET requests.  Also, since you're handling POST requests, you don't need to specify `AllowGet` for your JSON Response.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Patient(LoginModel.UserInfo Model)
{
    //code is here 
    return Json(Info);
}
```